# A simple program for splitting numbers does not display zeroes

Tags: c

I wrote a simple program in c that accepts two numbers and then splits the first number considering the digits of the second number like this:

> Input:
>   362903157 2313
>
> Output:
>
> 36
>   290
>   3
>   157

Everything works just fine, except when there are zeroes in the first number, my program skips them. For instance the upper example gives me this output:

> 36 293 1 570

And that is mycode:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int nDigits(unsigned i) {
    int n = 1;
    while (i > 9) {
        n++;
        i /= 10;
    }
    return n;
}

// find the highest multiple of 10
int multipleOfTen(int num){
    int multiple = 1;
    while(multiple <= num){
        multiple *= 10;
        if(multiple > num){
            multiple /= 10;
            break;
        }       
    }
    return multiple;
}

int main(){
    int n, m, digit; 

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    int lengthOfM = nDigits(m); 

    for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfM; i++){
        digit = m / multipleOfTen(m); //2

        for(int j = 1; j <= digit; j++){
            printf("%d", n/multipleOfTen(n));
            n = n% multipleOfTen(n);
        }
        printf("\n");

        m = m % multipleOfTen(m);
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

What should I change in my program so that the zeroes won't be ignored?

Comment: Obviously `j = 1` in `for(int j = 1; j <= digit; j++)`.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a little: by "divide" you probably mean "split" or "separate"?

Comment: Yes I think OP means split

Comment: The problem is the line `n = n% multipleOfTen(n);` So you get 362903157 --> 62903157 --> 2903157 --> 903157 --> 3157. I don't think there's an easy fix for this, you need to rethink how you extract digits from the first number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calling `multipleOfTen()` in each loop, call it once and save the result for both n and m. Then in each loop divide those results by 10

```
#include <stdio.h>

int nDigits(unsigned i) {
    int n = 1;
    while (i > 9) {
        n++;
        i /= 10;
    }
    return n;
}

// find the highest multiple of 10
int multipleOfTen(int num){
    int multiple = 1;
    while(multiple <= num){
        multiple *= 10;
        if(multiple > num){
            multiple /= 10;
            break;
        }
    }
    return multiple;
}

int main(){
    int n, m, digit;
    int i, j;
    int n10, m10;

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    int lengthOfM = nDigits(m);

    n10 = multipleOfTen(n); //get the multiple of ten once
    m10 = multipleOfTen(m); 

    for ( i = 0; i < lengthOfM; i++){
        digit = m / m10;
        m10 /= 10;
        for( j = 0; j < digit; j++){
            printf("%d", n/n10);
            n = n% n10;
            n10 /= 10;// divide by 10
        }
        printf("\n");
        m = m % multipleOfTen(m);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose an approach like this is inadmissible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void ) {
    char    n[64];
    char    m[64];
    char *  p   = n;
    int     i   = 0;
    int     c;

    scanf("%63[0-9] %63[0-9]", n, m);
    while ((c = m[i++]) != '\0') {
        int j = c - '0';
        while (j-- > 0) if (*p) putchar(*p++);
        putchar(' ');
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I first read the question, this was the very approach that I thought would be easy and relatively fool proof.

Answer (score 0):

when `n=903157` and after `n = n% multipleOfTen(n);` `n` becomes `3157` not `03157` so when u dividing again in line `printf("%d", n/multipleOfTen(n));` it prints `3` not `0` what you want!!
Fix your code to produce right output.